# python install via asdf: scrapy package not found even though pip install says requirement is already satisfied

Tags: arch-linux, python

I am running Arch Linux and I am up to date with packages.

I have [`asdf`](http://asdf-vm.com/) to manage run times and sdks ..etc.

In the root of my project, I have a `.tool-versions` file with:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ \cat .tool-versions                                                                                                                                                                       3.10.2
python 3.10.2
```

I then did `asdf reshim python`. Then I wanted to install the python package `scrapy` via `pip` and I get this:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ pip install scrapy                                                                                                                                                                        3.10.2
Requirement already satisfied: scrapy in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL>=16.2.0 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (22.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.0 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (36.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protego>=0.1.15 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: w3lib>=1.17.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: itemloaders>=1.0.1 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.1.3 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (58.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity>=16.0.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (21.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect>=0.9.1 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.5.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (2.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: itemadapter>=0.1.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tldextract in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: queuelib>=1.4.2 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=17.9.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (22.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: parsel>=1.5.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from scrapy) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath>=0.9.5 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from itemloaders>=1.0.1->scrapy) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.6.0 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from parsel>=1.5.0->scrapy) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.1.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from service-identity>=16.0.0->scrapy) (21.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.8.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.5 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=21.3.0 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (21.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from Twisted>=17.9.0->scrapy) (21.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.1.0 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from tldextract->scrapy) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from tldextract->scrapy) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-file>=1.4 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from tldextract->scrapy) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock>=3.0.8 in /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from tldextract->scrapy) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.0->scrapy) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->tldextract->scrapy) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->tldextract->scrapy) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/j/.asdf/installs/python/3.10.2/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.1.0->tldextract->scrapy) (2021.10.8)
```

When I run `pip list` I can see that `Scrapy` exists indeed!

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ pip list                                                                                                                                                                                  3.10.2
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
attrs              21.4.0
Automat            20.2.0
certifi            2021.10.8
cffi               1.15.0
charset-normalizer 2.0.12
constantly         15.1.0
cryptography       36.0.1
cssselect          1.1.0
filelock           3.6.0
hyperlink          21.0.0
idna               3.3
incremental        21.3.0
itemadapter        0.4.0
itemloaders        1.0.4
jmespath           0.10.0
lxml               4.8.0
parsel             1.6.0
pip                22.0.4
pipx               1.0.0
Protego            0.2.1
pyasn1             0.4.8
pyasn1-modules     0.2.8
pycparser          2.21
PyDispatcher       2.0.5
pyOpenSSL          22.0.0
queuelib           1.6.2
requests           2.27.1
requests-file      1.5.1
Scrapy             2.6.1
service-identity   21.1.0
setuptools         58.1.0
six                1.16.0
tldextract         3.2.0
Twisted            22.2.0
typing_extensions  4.1.1
urllib3            1.26.8
userpath           1.7.0
w3lib              1.22.0
zope.interface     5.4.0
```

Yet, the `scrapy` command isn't recognised, when I try to run my spider, I get:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot/gsscraper main !1 ?1 ❯ scrapy crawl gsspider -o stran.json                                                                                                                                             3.10.2
zsh: command not found: scrapy
```

If I run `asdf current` I get:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ asdf current                                                                                                                                                                              3.10.2
nodejs          ______          No version is set. Run "asdf <global|shell|local> nodejs <version>"
python          3.10.2          /home/j/code/bejebeje-bot/.tool-versions
```

What am I doing wrong here? why can't I run `scrapy`? I'm confused.

PS. I wanted to add the `asdf` tag, but I don't have enough points yet.

**UPDATE**

I ran `pip show scrapy` and I got:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ pip show scrapy                                                                                                                                                                           3.10.2
Name: Scrapy
Version: 2.6.1
Summary: A high-level Web Crawling and Web Scraping framework
Home-page: https://scrapy.org
Author: Scrapy developers
Author-email: 
License: BSD
Location: /home/j/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: cryptography, cssselect, itemadapter, itemloaders, lxml, parsel, protego, PyDispatcher, pyOpenSSL, queuelib, service-identity, setuptools, tldextract, Twisted, w3lib, zope.interface
Required-by:
```

I feel like the location ought to be somewhere under `/home/j/.asdf/shims/`! My `$PATH` has the following:

```
~/code/bejebeje-bot main !1 ?1 ❯ sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< "$PATH"                                                                                                                                                                3.10.2
/home/j/.asdf/shims
/opt/asdf-vm/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/home/j/code/go/bin
/home/j/.dotnet/tools
/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
/usr/bin/site_perl
/usr/bin/vendor_perl
/usr/bin/core_perl
/usr/local/go/bin
/home/j/code/go/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/home/j/code/go/bin
/home/j/.dotnet
/home/j/.dotnet/tools
~/programs/JetBrains Rider-2021.3.3/bin
```

Comment: Run `pip show scrapy` and check the `Location` field. The scrapy binary will be in the `bin` directory next to the `lib` directory of that field (`/home/wieland/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` -> `/home/wieland/.local/bin`). Does the scrapy binary exist in that directory? Is that directory in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Thanks @Wieland, see updated question. Is it normal that the packages aren't somewhere under `/home/j/.asdf/shims`?

Comment: I don't know enough about asdf to answer that question. If you want to run scrapy, add `/home/j/.local/bin`) to your `$PATH` (`path+=(/home/j/.local/bin)` in ZSH). I don't know if it's intended by asdf that python packages are installed in `~/.local` instead of somewhere else.